# Lead fill function in pandas using condition from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have a dataset containing a date index in the form MMMM-YY, the start date of a promotion, the discount value and the end date of the promotion.

As follows:

```
events = pd.DataFrame({'yyyyww': ['2022-01','2022-02','2022-03', '2022-04','2022-05','2022-06','2022-07','2022-08','2022-09','2022-10'],
                         'promo_start': ['2022-01','Nan','2022-03','Nan','2022-05','2022-06','Nan','Nan','2022-09','Nan'],
                         'disc': ['0.1','Nan',0.2,'Nan',0.2,0.4,'Nan','Nan',0.5,'NaN'],
                         'promo_end': ['Nan', '2022-02','Nan','2022-04','2022-05','Nan','2022-07','Nan','Nan','2022-10']})
```

[image]

I have attempted various combined `groupby` and `ffill` operations but I am unable to produce the desired output.

For each week in `YYYY-MM` I would like to be able to assess whether the promo was active by doing something akin to a lead fill operation such that the output is a dataframe with a boolean flag and the discount amount, as follows;

```
desired_output = pd.DataFrame({'yyyyww': ['2022-01','2022-02','2022-03', '2022-04','2022-05','2022-06','2022-07','2022-08','2022-09','2022-10'],
                         'promo_start': ['2022-01','Nan','2022-03','Nan','2022-05','2022-06','Nan','Nan','2022-09','Nan'],
                         'disc': ['0.1','Nan',0.2,'Nan',0.2,0.4,'Nan','Nan',0.5,'NaN'],
                         'promo_end': ['Nan', '2022-02','Nan','2022-04','2022-05','Nan','2022-07','Nan','Nan','2022-10'],
                         'promo_active': [True,True,True,True,True,True,True,False,True,True],
                         'promo_disc': [0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.4,0,0.5,0.5]})
```

[image]

Comment: Would your problem be solved by just checking if the value yyyyww equals promo_start or promo_end and fill in the Boolean in a new column called "promo_active"?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Due to the structure of the data there may be weeks/rows where both `promo_start` and `promo_end` may feature NaN but where the promo may still be active. Eg, if a promo lasts say two or more weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forward fill the `promo_start` then group the `promo_end` per promo start and backward fill the values, now check for the nulls to determine whether promo is active

```
g = events['promo_start'].ffill()
events['promo_active'] = events['promo_end'].groupby(g).bfill().notna()
```

---

```
    yyyyww promo_start  disc promo_end  promo_active
0  2022-01     2022-01   0.1      None          True
1  2022-02        None  None   2022-02          True
2  2022-03     2022-03   0.2      None          True
3  2022-04        None  None   2022-04          True
4  2022-05     2022-05   0.2   2022-05          True
5  2022-06     2022-06   0.4      None          True
6  2022-07        None  None   2022-07          True
7  2022-08        None  None      None         False
8  2022-09     2022-09   0.5      None          True
9  2022-10        None   NaN   2022-10          True
```

Comment: Seems to work as expected as very efficient.
Can you please explain how this works and how it can also be used to create the retrieve the applicable discount value in column `promo_disc`?

Answer (score 1):

A much longer approach than the one of Shubham but also less abstract:

```
# Test data
events = pd.DataFrame({'yyyyww': ['2022-01','2022-02','2022-03', '2022-04','2022-05','2022-06','2022-07','2022-08','2022-09','2022-10'],
                         'promo_start': ['2022-01','Nan','2022-03','Nan','2022-05','2022-06','Nan','Nan','2022-09','Nan'],
                         'disc': ['0.1','Nan',0.2,'Nan',0.2,0.4,'Nan','Nan',0.5,'NaN'],
                         'promo_end': ['Nan', '2022-02','Nan','2022-04','2022-05','Nan','2022-07','Nan','Nan','2022-10']})


# For loop to determine relevant periods
in_period = False
end_period = False

for i, row in events.iterrows():
    promo_start = events.at[i, "promo_start"]
    promo_end = events.at[i, "promo_end"]
    
    if promo_start != "Nan":
        in_period = True
        end_period = False
    
    if promo_end != "Nan":
        end_period=True 

    if in_period:
        events.at[i, "promo_start"] = "fill" if promo_start == "Nan" else promo_start
        events.at[i, "promo_end"] = "fill" if promo_end == "Nan" else promo_end

    in_period = False if end_period else in_period

# Fill values of relevant period
events = events.replace("fill", None)
events.promo_start = events.promo_start.ffill()
events.promo_end = events.promo_end.bfill()

# Create new column
def is_promo_active(row):
    return (row["yyyyww"] >= row["promo_start"]) and (row["yyyyww"] <= row["promo_end"])

events["promo_active"] = events.apply(lambda row: is_promo_active(row), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will review this method and report back.